# What could be causing this drop to zero FPS?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-technic-pack

The drop in FPS is not consistent with any particular area, it happens whether moving, or standing still. Near machinery, or not. In every dimension, in every location, in the air or below the sea or sea level. It will happen within minutes of joining the server, whether or not my PC had been on all day, or off for 12 hours. Restarted or not.

I've done everything I could think of, which I will list here.

- Installed Optifine (it helped a bit)
- Installed BetterFPS (it also helps, sometimes)
- Changed every possible video setting both with and without the above two mods, including 30+ variations of the options with/without them
  (Fast/Fancy settings, animations on/off, etc, etc)
- Allocated more/less RAM, currently sitting at 4, seems to be the 'most stable'
- Tried Fullscreen/windowed, windowed seem to be the more stable
- All drivers are updated, Java is updated, Windows is updated

Please check out the video below for PC specs, memory/cpu usage, etc.
I am in a mined out section with no machinery (no pipes, generators, farmers, etc) for at least 8 chunks. I am able to run this exact same online server, exact same area WITH machinery on my other, older PC with these specs: Windows 10, 32GB Ram, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 670,

Here is the video: [Youtube upload of FPS drop](https://youtu.be/td0wJXCzmuo)

I'm fairly used to diagnosing issues myself and finding solutions, but this one has me completely stumped and is aggravating, any help is Much Appreciated.

Comment: Check temperature of CPU/GPU. Check if game is actually running on GPU. Decrease view distance (but should be ok with 8-12 chunks), Java 1.8.0.221 does not seems latest, but should be ok. Still I think 155 mods are too much for 4GB, maybe try 8GB.

Comment: CPU temp hovered at around 164 c
GPU temp hovered at around 172 c
View distance was lowered/raised from 2 chunks to 32, no change / difference in FPS drop
Raised to 8GB, the drop in FPS occurred far more frequently and for much longer, changed back to 4GB, it was more stable

Comment: Update: One thing I just noticed, both in the video and the live game, there is an orange MB/s readout which seems to follow in the sudden FPS drop, however I have no information on what sort of data that represents. Goggle failed me on that one.

Comment: To close voters, OP _installed mods to try to fix the issue_. They did not install mods and then ask for help.